# Outlook Calendar Sync Issue 80070005

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, calendar, synchronization, http-status-code-401

I have a SharePoint 2013 calendar that needs unique permissions on it, allowing people who have NOT been granted access to the parent site access to this calendar.  I've broken inheritance on this calendar and granted Read permissions on the calendar to these non site members.  They are able to browse the calendar via Internet Explorer, but if they click the Connect to Outlook button in SharePoint, Outlook prompts for a username/password that can never authenticate.  The calendar is added to Outlook, but any attempts to sync results in an error message:

'Task SharePoint reported error (0x80070005): You do not have permission to view theis SharePoint List... HTTP 401'

I've tried the conventional wisdom of deleting the calendar from Outlook and adding again, but always get the same result.  The only thing that seems to fix the issue is to add the external user to the calendar's parent site as part of the members group.  This gives that external user access to other content in the parent site we want to restrict, so this is not an option.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Tks

Comment: I've done some poking around in the IIS logs after attempting to add the SharePoint calendar to Outlook and noticed the following:

2017-07-04 19:33:13 W3SVC1407251265 cw17spwfe 10.0.1.91 POST /sites/MySite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx - 443 - 10.5.14.15 Microsoft+Office+Outlook+2010+(14.0.6023)+Windows+NT+6.1 - 401 0 0 0

The client is Outlook and it's attempting to query lists.asmx which resides under _vti_bin.  My user permissions aren't set here (nor do I even think I can directly set permissions on _vti_bin folder).  Is this a known limitation of Outlook/SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

In order to Sync a SharePoint list or library to Outlook, [the user must have Collaborate permissions for the library or list](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Synchronize-SharePoint-2010-content-with-Outlook-2010-5ea811ca-8289-403b-902b-916572e203bf#__toc262734693) (2nd paragraph).

Comment: Tks.  I tried that.  Still getting access denied to the Collaborate user.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Ok you can try these troubleshooting steps: 1) in Outlook, delete the link, restart the computer and redo the "Cnhenct to Outlook".  I have also seen where these connections go bad for a certain computer, so if 1) doesn't work, try 2). Have the user log into a totally different machine and bring up outlook to see if it works there.  If not, try and reproduce step 1 on the new machine.  Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it figured out.  There are a couple of folders like Site Collection Images and Style Folders that have unique permissions under the calendar parent site.  My external users were not members of these libraries.  As soon as I added them, I was able to add my SharePoint calendar to Outlook.